# CORS Restful Webservice getting blocked

Tags: java, cors

Seems like there is a lot of CORS stuff on here. A million ways to handle it.

Converting over an app to Ionic. Because of [WKWebView](https://ionicframework.com/docs/wkwebview/)

This seems to run the code as local host on the ios. Which in tern means I need to handle CORS.

Followed this example.
https://amodernstory.com/2014/12/27/using-cors-headers-with-java-example/

At this point its just the web.xml has the CorsFilter setup. (defaults)

I thought I was going to have to do something in the code,  but nothing I have added seems to make any difference.

What happens, is I login,  and I trace that through and that seems to work fine.
Then the code pulls the users profile info. This is a seperate web service call.
That is getting blocked.

```
polyfills.js:3 POST [webserviceURL]/user/getUser 403 (Forbidden)
(index):1 Failed to load [webserviceURL]/user/getUser: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
    Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.
    The response had HTTP status code 403.
```

The first call to login goes through.  The second call never hits the web server.

Not sure why. Maybe I need to tell it to remember the Origin?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding proxy URLs:

From [Handling CORS issues in Ionic](https://blog.ionicframework.com/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/):

> Set up your ionic.project file to be something like:
>
> ```
> {
>   "name": "proxy-example",
>   "app_id": "",
>   "proxies": [
>     {
>       "path": "/api",
>       "proxyUrl": "http://cors.api.com/api"
>     }
>   ]
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add following in your web services header:
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8100

Also, You can use ionic native http plugin to resolve cors issue.

I have used this in our projects successfully to resolve cors issue.

Here is the link of this plugin: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/